# C++ Creating a generic class to initialize and support lookup of three lookup tables

Tags: c++, lookup-tables

I have a class that acts as a 2D lookup table.

The table is initialized in `LookupTable()` with the values.

And a value can be retrieved from the table by creating an instance of the table and using the notation `table[0][0]` which would return 1 in this case.

If you try to look an index that doesn't exist it will throw an exception.

My questions is, I want to define 3 tables not just one. And I don't want to duplicate the class 3 times to do that. Could anybody suggest a way to modify the existing class to support the initialization and lookup of 3 different tables?

```
class LookupTable {
    typedef std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> tableMap;
    tableMap mTable;

    class proxy {
        const std::map<int, int>& mMap;

    public:
        proxy(const std::map<int, int>& m): mMap(m) {
        }

        int operator[](int x) const {
            std::map<int, int>::const_iterator iter = mMap.find(x);
            if (iter == mMap.end()) {
                std::cout << "throw exception" << std::endl;
            } else {
                return iter->second;
            }
        }
    };

public:
    LookupTable() {
        // initialize table
        mTable[0][0] = 1;
        mTable[1][1] = 2;
        mTable[2][2] = 3;
        mTable[3][3] = 4;
    }

    proxy operator[](int x) const {
        std::map<int, std::map<int, int>>::const_iterator iter = mTable.find(x);
        if (iter == mTable.end()) {
            std::cout << "throw exception" << std::endl;
        } else {
            return proxy(iter->second);
        }
    }
};
```

Instead of having another class perhaps called `LookupTableOne` where I define another table with different values.

```
 class LookupTableOne {
        typedef std::map<int, std::map<int, int>> tableMap;
        tableMap mTable;
    
        class proxy {
            const std::map<int, int>& mMap;
    
        public:
            proxy(const std::map<int, int>& m): mMap(m) {
            }
    
            int operator[](int x) const {
                std::map<int, int>::const_iterator iter = mMap.find(x);
                if (iter == mMap.end()) {
                    std::cout << "throw exception" << std::endl;
                } else {
                    return iter->second;
                }
            }
        };
    
    public:
        LookupTableOne() {
            // initialize table
            mTable[0][0] = 5;
            mTable[1][1] = 6;
            mTable[2][2] = 7;
            mTable[3][3] = 8;
        }
    
        proxy operator[](int x) const {
            std::map<int, std::map<int, int>>::const_iterator iter = mTable.find(x);
            if (iter == mTable.end()) {
                std::cout << "throw exception" << std::endl;
            } else {
                return proxy(iter->second);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: `define 3 tables not just one.` soooo like `LookupTable the_tables[3];`?

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are implementing with your lookup table is already implemented in both `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` (which I would suggest for this problem). It allows const access that fails if the key does not exist and is called [`std::map::at(Key)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at).

If you construct your lookup map via one of the factories in [KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70753097/430766)'s answer, you don't need to actually write an extra class and especially not a proxy class:

```
auto const table = my_first_table(); // returns an unordered_map or map
auto const value = table.at(1).at(1);
```

If you want the `[]` syntax, you *can* still wrap the whole deal in your own class.

---

However, if you are looking such tables, possibly you are trying to optimise for performance. In that case both flavours of map will be inadequate. A `find` on a flat `std::array` (or, if necessary std::vector) will be much faster for small to medium instances. But you should benchmark if performance is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do not store variable data initialization in the constructor...

```
public:
    LookupTable() {}
```

Add a generic initialization function:

```
    LookupTable(const std::map<int, std::map<int, int>>& o) : mTable(o) {}
```

Create functions that create your lookup table.

```
  LookupTable my_first_table() {
     return { {
       { 0, { {0, 1} } },
       { 1, { {1, 2} } },
       { 2, { {2, 3} } },
       { 3, { {3, 4} } },
     } };
  }
  LookupTable my_second_table() {
     return { {
       { 0, { {0, 5} } },
       { 1, { {1, 6} } },
       { 2, { {2, 7} } },
       { 3, { {3, 8} } },
     } };
  }
  LookupTable my_second_table() {
     return { { .... } };
  }
```

Research factory pattern.

You could also do a template with a parameter or take an argument in the constructor and choose different code path depending on that parameter/argument.

Comment: thank you. I don't quite understand. For "Create functions that create your lookup table" , could you elaborate if you have time please? should these functions be inside the class? Could you show an example of two table so I understand?

Comment: `my_first_table` `my_second_table` are examples of functions that return an initialized `LookupTable` class. `should these functions be inside the class?` They could be `static` and inside the class, that depends on where you _want_ them to be.

Comment: You want to have one class definition, but several lookup tables with different values. That is reasonable and usually done. But where should the different values come from. Currently they are stored in the LookupTable constructor. Do you want to keep them there (for each kind of lookup table) or initialize from outside (e.g. in the code region, where you are using the tables)?

Comment: @Sebastian The tables have been defined offline manually. I just want to compile the tables into the code. Then in the code region where I need the tables I have a series of if conditions to retrieve a value from Table 1,2,3 etc.